# Why does the RMSE stay the same regardless of the algorithm that I use?

Tags: machine-learning, python, forecasting, recommender-system

I have a dataframe with users, items, and ratings that are either 0 or 1. There are more items than users, some users might rate lots of common items, and some not any common items at all. Here is a snippet, but in reality I have like 1500 users and 4000 items:

```
user     item     rating  
u1       i1       0
u1       i2       1
u2       i2       1
u2       i3       1
u3       i1       0
u3       i3       0
u3       i4       1
u3       i5       1
```

In order to recommend items to users, I used the `suprise` Python package.

```
import surprise
reader = Reader(rating_scale=(0, 1))
data = Dataset.load_from_df(df_user_activity, reader)

from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split
trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)
trainsetfull = data.build_full_trainset()

trainset_iids = list(trainset.all_items())
iid_converter = lambda x: trainset.to_raw_iid(x)
trainset_raw_iids = list(map(iid_converter, trainset_iids))

from surprise import NMF, SVD, SVDpp, KNNBasic, KNNWithMeans, KNNWithZScore, CoClustering
my_k = 15
my_min_k = 5
my_sim_option = {
    'name':'pearson', 'user_based':False, 
    }
algo = KNNWithMeans(
    k = my_k, min_k = my_min_k, sim_option = my_sim_option
    )

algo.fit(trainset)

from surprise import accuracy
predictions = algo.test(testset)
accuracy.rmse(predictions)

from surprise.model_selection import cross_validate
results = cross_validate(
    algo = algo, data = data, measures=['RMSE'], 
    cv=5, return_train_measures=True
    )

results['test_rmse'].mean()

algo.fit(trainsetfull)
```

I always get the RMSE around 0.38, regardless of what parameters or algorithm I use. What should I pay attention to? The original dataset, as described in the first paragraph, is a bit strange because there are much less users than items. Is it because of that?

Comment: Welcome to across Validated! What variables are you using to predict what variables?

Comment: @Dave user and item to predict the rating.